# How to read a squid log file with two formats in a line in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, squid, data-processing, logparser

I have to process a squid log file where each line represents a web request. The file is space delimited like any normal log file but also has request headers in the last column. For example,

```
1445210282000 - - - - CONNECT service.gc.apple.com:443 1.1 200 - Host:%20service.gc.apple.com%0D%0AUser-Agent:%20gamed/5.10.19.4.7.16.5.4.2%20(iPhone7,2;%209.0.2;%2013A452;%20GameKit-363.4)%0D%0AConnection:%20keep-alive%0D%0AProxy-Connection:%20keep-alive%0D%0A
```

As shown above the last column has different request headers in Header:Value format with %20, %0A and other characters. I need to extract each header in a column of its own for each line like the other columns.

What I've done is:

```
with open(filename, 'rt') as squidlog:
    for line in squidlog:
        cols = line.split()
        headers = cols[10].split('%0A')
```

But I'm not sure how to extract the `headers` variable and have all the constituent headers like Host, User-Agent as just another column in `cols` (or some better data structure like dict, names tuples etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can try "urllib2" package,

> headers= urllib2.unquote(cols[-1]).split()

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the best way of doing it but I have taken nagato's answer and expanded it to pull out the headers and values into a dictionary using some rather dark regular expression magic.

```
import urllib2
import re

#regex for extracting header from either start of line or "- " up to a colon
header_re = re.compile('(?:^|(?:- ))([^\s\.:]+):')

def parseLogLine(t):
    "Take a squid log line and return a dictionary of header:value"
    parse_dict = {}
    #unquote %0A etc to get normal lines chars and split
    encoded_lines = urllib2.unquote(t).split('\r\n')

    for l in encoded_lines:
        #regex match for header
        m = header_re.search(l)

        #check we find a match extract the header string 
        #and value string

        if m is not None:
            header_key = m.group(1)
            value = l[m.end():]
            parse_dict[header_key] = value

    return parse_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #quick test
    print parseLogLine("""1445210282000 - - - - CONNECT service.gc.apple.com:443 1.1 200 - Host:%20service.gc.apple.com%0D%0AUser-Agent:%20gamed/5.10.19.4.7.16.5.4.2%20(iPhone7,2;%209.0.2;%2013A452;%20GameKit-363.4)%0D%0AConnection:%20keep-alive%0D%0AProxy-Connection:%20keep-alive%0D%0A""")
```

The first part of the regular expression (?:^|(?:- )) is matching either the start of the line "^" or "- " using non-capturing parentheses, then the [^\s.:]+ looks for non-space text that is not a "." or a ":" before an actual ":" to match the header.

Hope this helps.